# C# Directory.GetCurrentDirectory and drives other than C:

Tags: c#

For some reason when my program is installed on a drive other than C:\ the code below (c# .net 2.0) is unable to find and run the program2.exe. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
try
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() +
                              "\\Folder\\program2.exe";
    proc.Start();
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to locate program");
}
```

Comment: What is the value of GetCurrentDirectory when it fails?  i.e. How are you running your main program?

Comment: The error could be something other than a directory error. Why don't you start by catching the exception and printing `ex.ToString()` to find out the real cause?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a security problem. It may be failing because you're trying to run something from a networked location.

Comment: All the comments above seem very rational, there is more than just "file not found" masked by the catch-all exception handler.  What's the real exception?  

And what's the value of the "FileName" property when it fails.

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I don't know the real exception, a customer passed this on to me and the only information I could get out of them was that it was installed on D and not c:\program files\. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be because your program is in the root folder of another drive, e.g. `R:\`, rather than a subdirectory, e.g. `R:\Program`?

For reasons such as this, it is considered bad practice in C# to concatenate paths using the literal backslash character. Instead, you should use `Path.Combine`:

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(
    Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
    "Folder",
    "program2.exe"
);
```

Furthermore, it may be that `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` does not point to the directory you think it does. In general, this could return any directory on your system, and is unrelated to where your program resides or was launched from. Therefore, I recommend to use one of these instead:

- If you are using WinForms, `Application.ExecutablePath`
- Otherwise, `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`